# Capacitor bridge present view controller [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: value parameter is nil'

Tags: ios, swift, ionic2, capacitor

Given an SDK I am trying to present its view in an Ionic-Capacitor app.

`self.bridge?.viewController` is available with it's `present` method from a Capacitor import

After loading the SDK, using: `self.bridge?.viewController?.present(someController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Produces the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: value parameter is nil'
terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

There are no errors indicated in the source code. When I inspect the error it leads me to the top of AppDelegate. Any suggestions are welcome on how to fix this.

Comment: The error leads pretty clearly to a line where JSON is going to be encoded and where the *JSONObject* is `nil`. Xcode contains a powerful debugger, use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet it's a Circular reference (or unsupported data types) cashing the JSON serialization error. But you need more information. Dive in and put in print statements:

https://andrewarrow.substack.com/p/installing-go-from-source-to-debug

i.e. you need to see line by line where the issue is. You need to edit the source code of this SDK and/or use XCode break points but I like prints statements way better.

Comment: Im really new to XCode... can I edit an SDK if opened separately? The SDK is not ours. It came from another org compiled.

Comment: If you don't have the source it's much harder. Would they be willing to give you the source? Or could you switch to another SDK that does the same thing you want? And/or write this SDK's features yourself. Might take less time than debugging without the source but it is possible. Break points in Xcode and the debugger will let you see exactly what is causing the issue but it's like 10x harder.